# Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 still asks for .NET 4.5

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012

I installed VS 2012 Professional Update 1 on Windows 7 SP1, x86. However when I try to compile a Windows App targeting .NET 4.5, I get the following error:

[image]

I installed .NET 4.5 as requested, but the same window keeps appearing. Windows is fully updated.

On the same machine I also run VS 2010 Professional SP1 and it works fine for .NET 4. What should I do in order to run VS 2010 and 2012 within the same OS?

Comment: Have you tried installing the .net framework 4.5 independently? If it is already showing up as installed then uninstall before installing again.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft says, .NET 4.5 is in-place update that replaces the old .NET Framework 4.0 assemblies. Have you tried to de-install 4.0 and after that to install 4.5?

This problem is also explained here (more or less): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did not try to uninstall VS 2010, I still develop some .net 4 projects and I am not sure VS 2012 allows me to menage them well (I already know that VS 2010 can target .net 4 applications, but...). Moreover, on the link you gave it is written: "We recommend that you install Visual Studio versions in the order in which they were released. For example, install Visual Studio 2010 before you install Visual Studio 2012." - this is certainly my case and it seems that the two VSes are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

I have all of the above installed, but on x64.

I recommend the following :

- uninstall vs2012 and .net framework 4.5
- reinstall .net framework 4.5 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653)
- install vs2012
- from what i read on this matter, .net 4.5 will not alter any of the other .net fw versions

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did as above (excepting OS reinstall, I'm still with x86) and sorry, no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2012 has known compatibility issues when running on Windows 7 Professional.

Try installing the fix for it:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36020

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the version of the .NET Framework that you want to target in Visual Studio 2012 before statrt the new project - see the answer here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb398197.aspx

Answer (score -2):

you can not create Windows App if you are using VS 2012 on Windows 7, this is the limitation.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for this? It seems counterintuitive, as .NET 4.5 works on Win 7, and VS 2012 can be installed on Win 7...

Comment: Perhaps you meant a Windows *Store* App? Because Windows apps of Winforms and WPF types still work perfectly fine.